# Question about the equality of variances of two populations

Tags: confidence-interval, inference

When finding the **confidence interval for the mean difference** between two groups of sample, under which assumption about the **equality of their population variances** should we take if no information about their population variances is given?

Is it correct that if **1** is within the **98%** confidence interval for the **ratio of variance**, then we can assume **equal population variance** when finding the confidence interval for the **mean difference**? At least that is what I understand from my lecture notes:[image][image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XiTW.png)

Comment: Without knowing the nature of your data or the sample sizes involved, it is impossible to answer. But ordinarily, you shouldn't use methods that assume equal variance, if you have doubts about that assumption. Methods for 'detecting' unequal variances generally have poor power, so it may be risky to use your confidence interval as assurance of equal variances.

Comment: Additionally, deciding which test to conduct based on the result of an equality of variance test leads to incorrect p values. So if you doubt equality of variance, just use a method that is robust to such assumptions. Google 1. Zimmerman t test variance or 2. Lakens Welch test for references for my first claim.

Comment: @BruceET Could you please kindly read the edited post with added information and explain?

Comment: @HeteroskedasticJim Thank you for the references.

Comment: See Addendum to my Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In R, the procedure `var.test` implements the standard F-test for equality of variances for data from two normal populations.

Here is an example, using samples of size $n = 20$ from two normal populations with respective variances $\sigma_1^2 = 49$ and $\sigma_2^2 = 25.$  The null hypothesis of equal variances is not rejected at the 5% level.

```
set.seed(2019)
x = rnorm(20, 50, 7);  y = rnorm(20, 50, 5)
var.test(x, y)

        F test to compare two variances

data:  x and y
F = 1.8786, num df = 19, denom df = 19, p-value = 0.1785
alternative hypothesis: 
   true ratio of variances is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.7435627 4.7461266
sample estimates:
ratio of variances 
          1.878575
```

The figure below shows the density function of $\mathsf{F}(19, 19),$ with vertical dotted lines at the critical values for a two-sided
test at the 5% level. The observed variance ratio $F = 1.8786$
lies between them.

[image]

This is not really an unusual case. According to the simulation below, the power of such a test is only about 30%.

```
set.seed(1234)
pv = replicate(10^5, 
       var.test(rnorm(20, 50, 7), rnorm(20,50,5))$p.value)
mean(pv < .05)
[1] 0.29359
```

---

**Addendum:** I'm not sure what is left to explain at this point,
but I will make a few comments and show some output from R.

(a) As I have hinted and @HeteroskedasticJim has documented: Whenever the goal is to test whether two normal population means are equal and there is doubt about equality of population variances, the recommended procedure is to do a Welch two-sample t 
test of the null hypothesis that population means are equal. 
[Thus I suppose both of us disagree with the boxed instruction with the "!" in you Question.]

For your data, that null hypothesis cannot be rejected. You can find formulas for the Welch test in you text, class notes, or online.

```
x = c(12,11,7,13,8,9,10,13);  y = c(13,11,10,6,7,4,10)
t.test(x,y)

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x and y
t = 1.1583, df = 10.771, p-value = 0.2718
alternative hypothesis: 
   true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -1.503134  4.824562
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
10.375000  8.714286
```

(b) If you had done a pooled two-sample t test (which requires the assumption that population variances are equal), then you would have $T = 1.1851, df = 13,$ and P-value = 0.2572, so again no rejection. (However as mentioned above, it is not recommended to do a 'composite test', first testing for equal variances; and if failing to reject, going on to do the pooled two-sample tests for equal means. The overall significance level of this rwo-test process is unclear.)

(c) If you use R's `var.test` procedure, mentioned in this Answer above, you can request a 98% CI, which agrees with what you say in your Question. The fact that
this CI includes $1$ does lead one to believe that population variances are equal (but it would be more direct to test the hypothesis that the ratio of population variances is 1.)

```
var.test(x,y, conf.lev=.98)

        F test to compare two variances

data:  x and y
F = 0.51743, num df = 7, denom df = 6, p-value = 0.4087
alternative hypothesis: 
    true ratio of variances is not equal to 1
98 percent confidence interval:
 0.06264264 3.72103337
sample estimates:
ratio of variances 
         0.5174279
```

The overall conclusion is that the data do not show convincing
evidence of a difference between the two fertilizers--neither in terms of their
population means nor in terms of their population variances.
The lack of significance is unsurprising on account of the small
sample sizes.